# PySpark DataFrame groupby into list of values?

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

Simply, let's say I had the following DataFrame:

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|
+-------------+----------+------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|      Michael|     Sales|  4600|
|       Robert|     Sales|  4100|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3000|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3300|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3900|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3000|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|
|         Saif|     Sales|  4100|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

How could I group by department and get all other values into a list, as follows:

| department | employee_name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | [James, Michael, Robert, James, Saif] | [3000, 4600, 4100, 3000, 4100] |
| Finance | [Maria, Scott, Jen] | [3000, 3300, 3900] |
| Marketing | [Jeff, Kumar] | [3000, 2000] |

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect_list` with `groupBy` clause

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy(col("department")).agg(collect_list(col("employee_name")).alias("employee_name"),collect_list(col("employee_name")).alias("salary"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets try with minimal typing;

```
df.groupby('department').agg(*[collect_list(c).alias(c) for c in df.drop('department').columns]).show()
```